# How to Use an Enum in an Angular Workspace

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an Angular workspace project with the following directory structure.

```
workspace
  typings
    index.d.ts
    auth.d.ts
  projects
    ...
    project1
      tsconfig.app.json
      src
        app
          app.conponent.ts
```

In the auth.d.ts file, I have defined an enum as follows:

```
export enum AuthStatus {
    active = 1;
    unActive = 2;
}
```

My tsconfig.app.json defines the paths as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "@typings": ["../../typings"]
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@typings‘
```

Is this a compilation issue? How can I use the enum properly?

I have tried moving the typings into a library and naming them as .ts files without the .d suffix.
Still doesn't work.

---

### resolved!!!

I renamed the .d.ts file to a .ts file, and it's working fine now!

Comment: Are you re-exporting your enum in the `index.d.ts` file?